# Error: Cannot find module '@angular-cli/plugins/karma'

Tags: angular, unit-testing, angular-cli, karma-jasmine

I am trying to use jasmine for writing unit test for Angular services, firstly it was unable to find module "angularcli/plugins/karma' after a quick search i changed every instance of "angularcli" to "@angularcli" but still on running "ng test" problem exist. Here is the error:

```
20 07 2018 17:07:57.919:ERROR [config]: Error in config file!
 { Error: Cannot find module '@angular-cli/plugins/karma'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:571:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:497:25)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:626:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:20:18)
    at module.exports (D:\new project\MarsWeb\MarsWeb-FrontEnd\karma.conf.js:13:7)
    at Object.parseConfig (D:\new project\MarsWeb\MarsWeb-FrontEnd\node_modules\karma\lib\config.js:396:5)
    at new Server (D:\new project\MarsWeb\MarsWeb-FrontEnd\node_modules\karma\lib\server.js:56:20)
    at Promise (D:\new project\MarsWeb\MarsWeb-FrontEnd\node_modules\@angular\cli\tasks\test.js:45:33)
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at Class.run (D:\new project\MarsWeb\MarsWeb-FrontEnd\node_modules\@angular\cli\tasks\test.js:23:16)
    at Class.run (D:\new project\MarsWeb\MarsWeb-FrontEnd\node_modules\@angular\cli\commands\test.js:122:25)
    at resolve (D:\new project\MarsWeb\MarsWeb-FrontEnd\node_modules\@angular\cli\ember-cli\lib\models\command.js:261:20)
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at Class.validateAndRun (D:\new project\MarsWeb\MarsWeb-FrontEnd\node_modules\@angular\cli\ember-cli\lib\models\command.js:240:12)
    at Promise.resolve.then.then (D:\new project\MarsWeb\MarsWeb-FrontEnd\node_modules\@angular\cli\ember-cli\lib\cli\cli.js:140:24)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7) code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND' }
```

i have updated karma.conf.js to work with @angular-cli still node can not find the module

here is my Karma.conf.js

```
module.exports = function (config) {
  config.set({
    basePath: '',
    frameworks: ['jasmine', '@angular-cli'],
    plugins: [
      require('karma-jasmine'),
      require('karma-chrome-launcher'),
      require('karma-jasmine-html-reporter'),
      require('karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter'),      
      require('@angular-cli/plugins/karma')
    ],
    client: {
      clearContext: false
    },
    files: [
      { pattern: './src/test.ts', watched: false }
    ],
    preprocessors: {
      './src/test.ts': ['@angular-cli']
    },
    mime: {
      'text/x-typescript': ['ts','tsx']
    },
    coverageIstanbulReporter: {
      reports: [ 'html', 'lcovonly' ],
      fixWebpackSourcePaths: true
    },
    coverage: {
      reports: {
        html: 'coverage',
        lcovonly: './coverage/coverage.lcov'
      }
    },
    angularCli: {
      environment: 'dev'
    },
    reporters: config.angularCli && config.angularCli.codeCoverage
              ? ['progress', 'coverage-istanbul']
              : ['progress', 'kjhtml'],
    port: 9876,
    colors: true,
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
    autoWatch: true,
    browsers: ['Chrome'],
    singleRun: false
  });
};
```

And this is dev dependencies from package.json

```
"devDependencies": {
        "@angular/cli": "^1.2.5",
        "@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.2.0",
        "@types/jasmine": "2.5.38",
        "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
        "codelyzer": "~2.0.0",
        "jasmine-core": "~2.5.2",
        "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~3.2.0",
        "karma": "~1.4.1",
        "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.0.0",
        "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
        "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^0.2.0",
        "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
        "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
        "karma-remap-istanbul": "^0.6.0",
        "protractor": "~5.1.0",
        "ts-node": "~2.0.0",
        "tslint": "~4.5.0",
        "typescript": "^2.4.2"
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change `@angular-cli` to `@angular/cli`  in all the occurences.

Hope this helps!

Comment: @Can you please mark my answer as answered then? :-)

Comment: yeah i did, SO was not allowing to mark your answer as answered so early. :)

Comment: No problem. Thanks!  :-)

Comment: It is 2022 and this does not work. My packages were already @angular/cli to begin with.

Comment: @chitgoks for more recent versions of angular, its       `require('@angular-devkit/build-angular/plugins/karma')`

Comment: @dgamma3 this is correct. I had to modify quite some lines for this.